# Force www to https in Express NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, https

I build a NodeJS app with express and in Firefox when I type domain name .com it's not redirecting to https://www.<domain_name>.com

Can someone help on how to redirect <domain_name>.com and www.<domain_name>.com with https?

```
  let host = req.headers.host;
  if (!host.match(/^www\..*/i)) {
    return res.redirect(301, "https://www." + host + req.url);
  }
  next();
}
```

I tried the above one but no luck on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit your http server configuration accordingly:

```
apache: etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default
```

change to this:

```
RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

or

```
nginx: etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

change to this:

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name your_domain.com www.your_domain.com;
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

If you still experience issues, edit .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?supergenscript\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.supergenscript.com/$1 [R=301, L]
```